# 'Object Required' to send Email

Tags: email, ms-access, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a function so that it sends an email to an Email address which is in one of my queries (UpcomingBirthday). I've got this code in a function and then in a macro autoexec so it runs when I load my database.

```
Public Function EmailSend()
Dim imsg As Object
Dim iconf As Object
Dim flds As Object
Dim schema As String

Set imsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set flds = iconf.Fields


schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "smtp.live.com"
flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 25
flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "MyEmail@hotmail.com"
flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "MyPassword"
flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = False
flds.Update

With imsg
    Call EmailSend(UpcomingBirthday.[Email], "MyEmail@hotmail.com", "Birthday Promotion!", "<html>Happy Birthday! <p> Our records indicate that you're eligible for a birthday promotion.</p></html.")
    Set .Configuration = iconf
    .Send
End With

Set iconf = Nothing
Set imsg = Nothing
Set flds = Nothing
 End Function
```

Now when I try to run this code, it tells me "**Run-Time Error 424 - Object Required**" and highlights this line when I go to Debug: *Call EmailSend(UpcomingBirthday.[Email], "MyEmail@hotmail.com", "Birthday Promotion!",* etc.. So what I need it to do is that the values from the column 'Email' in my query 'UpcomingBirthday' and then send an email to them.

If anyone could help me by telling me what I need to do to fix this error that'd be great! And also if you could just scan the code and see if it's fine (as in should it work)? Thanks! :)

Comment: Were you planning on using recursion in your code? You define your function as `Public Function EmailSend()` and one of the statements in that function is `Call EmailSend`. When a procedure (`Sub` or `Function`) calls itself without any exit condition things tend to "go badly".

Comment: If I change my `Call EmailSend` to `Call SendEmail` it says *Sub or Function not defined*. So yea I think the recursion is deliberate? I think that the problem lies within the `UpcomingBirthday.[Email]`

Answer (score 0):

The `Call EmailSend` statement within `Public Function EmailSend` is clearly problematic. If you want to assign values to the properties of `imsg` (a `CDO.Message` object) then just do something like

```
With imsg
    .To = "recipient@example.com"
    .From = "MyEmail@hotmail.com"
    .Subject = "Birthday Promotion!"
    '' and so on
    .Send
End With
```

Also, we don't know what `UpcomingBirthday` really is because it is defined elsewhere.

You might want to save yourself some bother and just use the `SendEmail` function available for download here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx

Comment: Hmm ok well I went with the more simple approach and changed it to what you said, but when I say `.Body = "Happy Birthday etc"`, it gives me an error *Object doesn't support this property or method*.
So I took out the .Body part just to see what happens, and then it highlights `.Send` and says: *The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.*

Comment: Or if I download the SendEmail function that you provided, will I still be able to automatically update the `.To` field to an email address from my UpcomingBirthday query? Thanks.

Comment: @NightSpy2 Sure, just look at the code: `ToAddress` is the third item in the argument list.